# Sending DMs to specific people: Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having some issues sending a PM to a specific person. I know how to send a DM to the author of the message. However I am looking to trying to send a DM directly to a specific person.

```
async run(message, args) {
    if (args == 'mock') {
      console.log(message.author);
      message.send(Bloodmorphed,
        '1. *No bad mana mocks (funki manas)* \n' +
        '2. Minimum 500k smite must be used at all times \n' +
        '3. No causing the game to lag using skills on attack/hit/struck \n' +
        '4. Must use delerium on attack/attack or attack/hit \n' +
        '5. No use of stash is allowed \n' +
        '6. No 2nd character to view is allowed \n' +
        '7. Matches should only have the two duelist and the host in the game \n' +
        '8. No stopping your attack once you start unless the opponent and host agree \n' +
        '9. 10 minute limit \n' +
        '10. Dueling area should be cleared by the host prior to the duel \n' +
        '11. Must use Nv Valkyrie or Dopplezon \n' +
        '12. Duels last until someone dies \n' +
        '13. Any death after joining the game will count as a loss \n' +
        '14. Each player will have a chance to be 2nd joiner and 3rd joiner. Higher ranked player will be 2nd joiner first. If both are un-ranked, the challenged will be 2nd joiner first \n' +
        '15. Duels must be in a neutral game \n' +
        '16. No mercs / summoned units allowed \n');
    } else if (args == 'legit') {
      message.send('Legit rules test');
    } else {
      message.reply('Error: The command you have entered is correct. Use !help for help on commands.');
    }
  }
}
```

I can't quite seem to figure out how discord even handles DMs in the first place. Going through the documents in discord.js and discord,js-commando doesn;t seem to help much.

Comment: Alright so I'm now using: `message.mentions.members.first()` but I'd rather not use it. It does work, however if I use it in args... it only returns `@id` which I guess doesn't work.

Comment: So another issue. If i have more than one arguement. Say: `!command arg1 arg2` then `args[0]` you would think would be arg1 but it is not. I have to add up to the max in a variable and check against it then. Which works, but kind of sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord handles DMs through the User object (what GuildMember extends), as you can tell [from the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User). From here, it implements a TextBasedChannel, or the DM channel you're talking about. To send a message to a user, you would do something along these lines:

```
async run(message, args) => {
    message.author.send("Hello, this is a DM!");
}
```

Or, if you want to use a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user)...

```
async run(message, args) => {
    message.member.user.send("Hello, this is a DM!");
}
```

There's a few special things about DMs on Discord.js, though.

1. If you're sharding, all DMs will go to Shard 1. ([Source](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sharding))
2. You will always have permission to send embeds.
3. The user can have DMs disabled.

To detect a DM message, I like to do this with my message event:

```
bot.on("message", async m => {
    m.isDM = (m.guild ? false : true);
});
```

This works because if a DM message comes in, the guild object will be null. Also, please keep in mind that when sending a DM, there is no way for the bot to check if the user has DMs disabled. This means it's really important to catch all DM messages for failure. Here's an example.

````
async run(message, args) => {
    message.author.send("Hello, I'm a DM that handles if users don't have permission!").catch(e => {
        message.channel.send("There was an internal error attempting to send you a message.\n" + "```js\n" + e.stack + "\n```";
    }
}
````

As per request, here's an example of using everything above in commando:

````
client.on("commandRun", cmd => {
    cmd.message.message.isDM = (m.guild ? false : true);
    cmd.message.message.author.send("Hello, I'm a DM that handles if users don't have permission!").catch(e => {
        cmd.message.message.channel.send("There was an internal error attempting to send you a message.\n" + "```js\n" + e.stack + "\n```";
    });
});
````

Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Awesome. I think I will most likely use mentions though, because it is easier to catch the data that way, then have it check a database if need be. Now I am curious about the arguments. `!command arg1 arg2` I am using `discord.js-command` API for easier command making. My question is... `args[0]` I would want to pull full `arg1` but in reality is pulls `a` from `arg1` is there a way to have it recognize it as `arg1`?

Comment: A little more detailed explanation: `!challenge ranked @User` (I may reverse the order, which would make it harder). If i print out `args[0]` it would print out `r` in `ranked`. This is not really what I want.

Comment: @William Your title clearly says "Sending DMs to Specific People", as well as your description. This answers the said question. The issue you've showed in the comments is not related to the question whatsoever. If you have a separate question, you should post it as a separate question entirely instead of just posting it in the comments of this question and rejecting the answer.

Comment: I didn't reject the answer, so whats with the hostility? Jesus.

Comment: I apologize if that comment came off more hostile than intended. I was merely trying to point out that if you have a separate question, you should make another thread. I apologize again for how hostile I was previously.

Comment: Hello, this question is relevant to this answer: you use `bot.on('message')` is there one for running commands? I tried `bot.on('command')` but doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to relate to add an example of the commando library.